# Define order for properties in model mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

we are showing model properties in grid format using DisplayForModel().

I just want to know is there any way we can define the order for the meta data properties.

For ex:

Current display: Party, PartyRole, Id, Title FromDate, ThruDate

Desired display: Title, Party, PartyRole, FromDate, ThruDate, Id

Is it possible in any way ???

display template - object.cshtml

```
@functions
{
bool ShouldShow(ModelMetadata metadata)
{
    return metadata.ShowForDisplay
        && metadata.ModelType != typeof(System.Data.EntityState)
        && !metadata.IsComplexType
        && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(metadata);
}
}
<table>
<tr>
    @if (TempData["header"] == null)
    {
        foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => ShouldShow(pm)))
        {
            if (property.DisplayName != "Id")
            { 
        <th>
            @property.GetDisplayName()
        </th>
            }
        }
        TempData["header"] = "true";
    }
</tr>
<tr>
    @foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => ShouldShow(pm)))
    {
        if (prop.DisplayName == "Id")
        {
             <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = @Html.Display(prop.PropertyName)  }) </td>
        }
        else
        { 
           <td>@Html.Display(prop.PropertyName)</td>
        }
    }
    </tr>
</table>
```

grid.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<object>
<div class="grid">
@Html.DisplayForModel()

</div>
<div id="my-dialog"></div>
```

Thanks a lot in advance..

Comment: Are you using the default `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`? Any reason why you can't use [`[Display(Order = ...)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.order.aspx) on the model's properties? The `Properties` enumerable is sorted by that attribute value by default. (Not a rhetorical question - only asking, because I'm not 100% sure I understand the requirements).

Comment: I took the liberty of promoting it to an answer then. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the default `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`, you can use the `DisplayAttribute`'s `Order` property ([info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.order)) on the properties of the model, i.e. (guessing at your ViewModel):

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [Display(Order = 1)]
    public string Party { get; set; }

    [Display(Order = 2)]
    public SomeRole PartyRole { get; set; }

    [Display(Order = 5)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Order = 0)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Order = 3)]
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Order = 4)]
    public DateTime ThruDate { get; set; }
}
```

`ModelMetadata.Properties` is sorted by that attribute value by default.

Note that in some cases (but see below!), this really only makes sense when using inheritance in your models - because if all the properties are defined on a single ViewModel class, it's mostly simpler to just put them in the correct order in that class in the first place, i.e.:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Party { get; set; }
    public SomeRole PartyRole { get; set; }
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ThruDate { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

**Late addition, 2021**: **However**, the source order is actually an implementation detail - properties are not guaranteed to be returned by Reflection in source order (although they often are in practice). The safe way of doing this is to use some kind of `Order` property.

In the case of MVC, you still need to use the `Display(Order = ...)` attribute like above, but in other cases - where the consumer of the attribute is your own code, note that there's a hack that doesn't require you to define the order manually - you can create your own `OrderAttribute` and use the `CallerLineNumber` attribute in its constructor to ensure ordering properties decorated with your attribute (`[Order]`) by source order "automatically":

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public sealed class OrderAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Order { get; }
    public OrderAttribute([CallerLineNumber] int order = 0)
    {
        Order = order;
    }
}
```